# How to unlock file locked by pexif

Tags: python, windows-7, exif, filelock

I'm using the [PEXIF module](https://github.com/bennoleslie/pexif) to read and edit EXIF data in JPEG files. After reading a file's data I would like to rename the file, but by then it is locked and `os.rename()` throws a `WindowsError`.

```
import pexif, os
f = 'oldName.jpg'
img = pexif.JpegFile.fromFile(f)
print img.exif.primary.ExtendedEXIF.DateTimeOriginal
os.rename(f, 'newName.jpg')
```

How can I unlock the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `fromFd` instead:

```
f = 'oldName.jpg'
with open(f, "rb") as fd:
    img = pexif.JpegFile.fromFd(fd)
print img.exif.primary.ExtendedEXIF.DateTimeOriginal
os.rename(f, 'newName.jpg')
```

The file handle will be closed when the `with` block's scope ends, so the rename will work.

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly what I was asking for, but likely what I _should_ have been asking for :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised fromFile doesn't release the file handle. Sounds like it's a bug in the library

Comment: I patched pexif to correctly close the file handle and submitted a pull request here: https://github.com/bennoleslie/pexif/pull/1 - hope the author accepts it.

Comment: It definitely is a bug in the pexif library. I've merged the pull request as above. Thanks Aphex.